# ggplot geom_line plot issue

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a big time series data set with thousands of values, and I am trying to plot a simple `geom_line` line plot, something like this:

[image]

But with my data I get this:

[image]

How can I fix this in R?

My data (df) structure is such that let's say I have `3` pixels in an `area`, and each `pixel` has a daily value.

Sample (dummy) data:

```
Pixel day      value
1     01/01/01  0
2     01/01/01  0.2
3     01/01/01  0.5
1     01/02/01  0.5
2     01/02/01  0.4
3     01/02/01  1
1     01/03/01  1
2     01/03/01  0.6
3     01/03/01  1.5
```

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x= day, y=value)) +
  geom_line() + 
  xlab("")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happened because you have multiple observations by day, so either you can summarise or plot one line per Pixel

### Sample data

```
df <-
  structure(list(Pixel = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), 
                 day = structure(c(11323, 11323, 11323, 11354, 11354, 11354, 
                                   11382, 11382, 11382), class = "Date"), value = c(0, 0.2, 
                                                                                    0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 1, 1, 0.6, 1.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                         -9L))
```

### Original code

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x= day, y=value)) +
  geom_line() + 
  xlab("")
```

[image]

### Adding group aesthetic

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x= day, y=value, group = Pixel)) +
  geom_line() + 
  xlab("")
```

[image]

### Summarising code

```
df %>% 
  #Calculating mean by day
  group_by(day) %>% 
  summarise(value = mean(value,na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= day, y=value)) +
  geom_line() + 
  xlab("")
```

[image]

Comment: Can I `summarize` the data day-wise for every pixel directly in `ggplot` code, if so can you please add that to your answer?

Comment: Sure @Mandalorian, just updated my answer!